# $nin within $project aggregation pipeline MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am creating a mongoDB aggregation pipeline with a `$project` step in it. I want to filter some subdocuments inside the `allFields` array with a `$nin` condition (see code snippet inside the `cond` step). However this query gives me an error stating the following: Unrecognized expression '$nin'

When I change `$nin` to `$in` everything is fine and works as expected. Why does `$nin` give an error here?

```
$project: {
    "TransactionMonth": 1,
    "allFields": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$allFields",
            "as": "allFields",
            "cond": {
                "$nin": [ "$$allFields.CustomerType", ["A", "B", "C"] ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) is a query operator, you can use in `$match` stage in aggregation only,

You can try `$not` and `$in` operators to handle your case,

```
$project: {
    "TransactionMonth": 1,
    "allFields": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$allFields",
            "as": "allFields",
            "cond": {
                "$not": {
                  "$in": [ "$$allFields.CustomerType", ["A", "B", "C"] ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```